# How can I debug a function that performs most work in a temporary buffer?

Tags: debugging, edebug

I've been able to do this before, but I can't remember the 'recipe' of sorts.

Say I've got the following function:

```
(defun fancy-stuff ()
  (with-current-buffer (get-crazy-process-output)
    (do-crazy-post-process)))
```

I want to debug the crazy post-processing and be able to see where/when it moves point in that buffer.

I've of course instrumented `do-crazy-post-process` with `edebug-defun`, but when I step through the code, I have no visual indication of how point is moving in the temporary buffer.

Comment: Did you try `M-x debug-on-entry do-crazy-post-process`? What did you try? The question might be clearer if you described what you tried.

Comment: @Drew See edit.

Comment: In edebug, pressing p will temporarily select the current buff in a window and show where point is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

True to form, I found the answer while asking the question.  For anyone else who finds this useful:

```
(view-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
```

If you place this form anywhere in the form that's being instrumented, you'll see point move in real-time as you step through the code.  For example,

```
(defun fancy-stuff ()
  (with-current-buffer (get-crazy-process-output)
    (view-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
    (do-crazy-post-process)))
```

Comment: Please consider showing how you use that in connection with the code in your question.

Comment: @Drew Good advice, thank you :-) See edit. It's been a while since I've been on SE – my habits are a little rusty.

Comment: It turns out it is not a good idea to use `view-buffer-other-window` for this purpose because it makes the buffer read-only. Can cause a very confusing debugging experience.

Comment: @LionelHenry interesting -- is there an alternative folks should prefer?

Answer (score 2):

I found this question because I was having trouble debugging a function that used `with-temp-buffer`. Using edebug one can press <kbd>p</kbd> to temporarily switch to where point is, but this isn't much good because the temp buffer will be gone once edebug is finished.

The easy way in this case is to replace

```
(with-temp-buffer
  stuff)
```

with

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "temp-buffer")
  stuff)
```

And then use the trick above, so:

```
(with-current-buffer (get-buffer-create "temp-buffer")
  (view-buffer-other-window (current-buffer))
  stuff)
```

Now the temp buffer will still be around afterwards for inspection.